# how to consume a RESTful web service as a jar in JAVAEE

Tags: spring, rest, jakarta-ee, jar, ws-client

I have a RESTful web service developped using (Spring-Java)
and it is a JAR file

I have created a Java EE web app that must consume this web service (using Eclipse)
running on WildFly9

How can I do to run the web service (JAR file) so that the web app can consume it ?

Comment: How does that make sense? Why should the web server hit itself once more via HTTP in order to transfer representational state?

Comment: Since I don't have the project that contains the web services and I just have a Jar generated from that project  , my web app must access to these web services through this jar , any way to do that ?